# Multitenancy issue with AAD

Tags: azure

We have a multitenant multitier scenario in Azure AAD  where a client app calls multiple Web APIs. These WebAPIs in turn calls other WebAPIs.
Every time we add a take new API dependency , we see that users from other than the app tenancy is unable to logon. We see the below error

AADSTS65005: The app needs access to a service……

My question is what is the best practice or guidance around multitenancy. Do we need to provide the admin consent every time we add a new dependency

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding a new permission requirement to the Application object. The permission grants are not created on the service principals automatically, it always requires consent. You can quite easily grant this in a single-tenant scenario, but multi-tenant is harder.

Since it would make no sense that I could just add permissions to read all users' mailboxes when it could not before, the only option is to run admin consent for each tenant again.

The v2 endpoint allows you to handle this in an easier way as it allows dynamic/incremental consent, where you can specify a new scope from the client. Though even then you would have to provide some notification to the users that they can't use the new functionality until their admin grants consent.